# trigger an update of selectInput based on link selection from observeEvent in R Shiny

Tags: r, pdf, shiny, hyperlink, reactive

I would like to dynamically change a selectInput pdf file based on which link has been chosen from valueBox texts.

In the original code, link1 and link2 found in the valueBoxes of a separate tab navigate to a common tab panel with a pdf viewer and the first pdf in the choices available. So far, navigation to the common tab panel works, but I would also like event to change pdf files based on the valueBox selection.

Simplified version (without the navigation) is as follows:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session){

observeEvent(input$link1, {
updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "pdf_selection"
, choices = c("pdf1" = "location/pdf1.pdf"
, "pdf2" = "location/pdf2.pdf")
, selected = "pdf1")
})
observeEvent(input$link2, {
updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "pdf_selection"
, choices = c("pdf1" = "location/pdf1.pdf"
, "pdf2" = "location/pdf2.pdf")
, selected = "pdf2")
})

output$pdfView <- renderUI({
tags$iframe(style = "height:800px;width:100%", src = input$pdf_selection)
})

output$stat1 <- renderValueBox({
valueBox(subtitle = "fact 1", value = actionLink(inputId = "link1", label = HTML("Some statistic to report1")))
})

output$stat2 <- renderValueBox({
valueBox(subtitle = "fact 2", value = actionLink(inputId = "link2", label = HTML("Some statistic to report2")))
})

})

shinyUI(fluidPage(
dashboardPage(dashboardBody(
useShinyjs()
# Row showing the linked valueBoxes
, fluidRow(valueBoxOutput("stat1"), valueBoxOutput("stat2"))

, selectInput(inputId = "pdf_selection"
, label = "select pdf"
, choices = c("pdf1" = "location/pdf1.pdf", "pdf2" = "location/pdf2.pdf")
, selected = "")

# For viewing the selected pdf file
, htmlOutput("pdfView")
)

)))
```

There doesn't appear to be any update to the selected choice after a link is selected. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, the problem seems to be from the `observeEvent` lines. For selected choices, the "selected" choice should be the defined choice and not the label. So instead of `selected = "pdf1`, it should be `”selected" = "location/pdf1.pdf"`.